# Extracting data from JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, object, stringify

The data I receive back from my JSON.stringify looks like this.

```
 {"action":"deleted","data":{"latitude":9,"longititude":8,"_type":"locationcurrent","id":49,"user":"7"}}
```

But I can not seem to get the data inside of the objects. Mainly I want the value for action, "deleted", and the values for my data, like id:"49". But im having problems using this equation to try and get the data out.

```
 function replacer(key, value) {
            if (typeof value === "string") {
                return value;
            }
            return undefined;
        }

        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(message, replacer);
        console.log(jsonString);
```

All I get back from this is,

```
 data:{}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to do.  But if you are bringing down JSON, than you want to do `var obj = JSON.parse(message)` If you are creating a JSON string(as you are doing above) and want to access properties, than its the same `var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);` Then `var actionValue = obj.action;`

Comment: you don't need a reviver to get data out. in fact, you shouldn't stringify() it at all if you want to use the data as discrete pieces. `message.action` and `message.data.id` seem to be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the first `value` that is passed to the `replacer` is the object itself. You replace this object by `undefined` because it is not of the type `string`.

You need it change it that way:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
    if ( key === '' || typeof value === "string") {
        return value;
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

But as [Phatjam98](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850715/phatjam98) said, it does not make much sense to filter out one value that way.